# Тире не между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сказуемые

Дайте, пожалуйста, правила на тире **не** между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: Тире  применяется во многих синтаксических конструкциях (практически во всех), поэтому уточните, что конкретно Вас интересует.

Comment: Если корректно, то перед прилагательным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится: **Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый… (П.); Земля велика и прекрасна (Ч.); Вишнёвый сад мой! (Ч.); Небо без единого облачка; Люди здесь необыкновенной доброты.**

Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:

1) при логическом или интонационном членении предложения:Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); **Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная (Каз.);**

2) при наличии однородных сказуемых: **Ритм суворовского училища — чёткий, быстрый, военный (Газ.); Он сильно изменился: походка, движения, черты лица, даже взгляд — мягче, спокойнее, проще;**

3) **при параллелизме конструкций (частей предложения): Ночь — тёплая, небо — синее, луна — серебристая, звёзды — блестящие.**

11. В сносках (примечаниях, объяснениях) тире отделяет объясняемое слово от объяснения (независимо от формы выражения сказуемого): **Посейдон — в древнегреческой мифологии бог морей; Пегас — считается символом поэтического вдохновения.**

Д. Э. Розенталь Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.

Comment: Чего-то я не понимаю. Вопрос: "Тире НЕ между подлежащим и сказуемым". Ответ: о тире МЕЖДУ подлежащим и сказуемым (сказуемое выражено прилагательным) . И ответ принят (?!).

Comment: Да, согласна с Вами, вопрос абсолютно неясный, надо было его отредактировать и уточнить у автора, что означает частица НЕ и о каких прилагательных идет речь. Или хотя бы сейчас внести изменения  в вопрос в соответствии с ответом.

Comment: Думаю, речь идет о том, когда сказуемое выражено прилагательным.